# how to upload File in angularjs frontend

Tags: angularjs, file, upload, protocols

I want to Upload a data api with the following signature but I want to double check how the data is received.I have used just ordinary modules in angular to upload the file but I want to check how the file pushed to the api. I want the file to be collection of bytes as  it reaches the api but here am uploading the just the file. Does the internal transfer protocol change it to bytes ?[image]

notice the file has type of collection of bytes.
How should I upload that

Answer (score 1):

For this I use the [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).  Using the Upload service to call your api like this:

```
Upload.upload({
  url: '/api/uploadFile',
  fields: {fileName: 'fileName', fileExt: '.doc'},
  file: file
})
```

The file will be uploaded as type [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) and you can do what you need to on the back end.

Here is a snippet for the download using [FileSaver,js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/):

```
$http.post('/api/downloadFile', 'fileName', {responseType: "arraybuffer"}).
  success(function(data) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: '.doc' });
    saveAs(blob, file.fileName);
  })
```

Comment: Here is the problem I cant access the api,I can only consume

Comment: Good thanks men,Am thinking putting it on plunker so will let you know

Comment: If this one worked are you able to accept the answer?